# How to find out the current group level of a range in excel for web using office-script

Tags: excel, vba, office-scripts, excel-online

I am trying to find out how to identify the current group level of a range in office-script.
Based on the documentation I was only able to find the `group` or `ungroup` methods.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-group-member(1)
However, if my row is already grouped I will create a sub-group with these methods.
The only workaround I can think of is to ungroup multiple times and the to group to my desired level.

In vba you were able to read/write to the `OutlineLevel` property

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.outlinelevel

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is currently supported. I don't see a property for it in either Office Scripts or Office.js

Comment: Yes that's what I thought as well. Shame

Answer (score 1):

These APIs are not supported in Excel JS add-ins at this moment. You can suggest this at [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform)